# python selenium how to set firefox BrowserCommunicationPort

Tags: python, selenium

c#

```
ffDriverService.BrowserCommunicationPort = 1000
```

python

```
?
```

i only find this code

:param port: Run the remote service on a specified port.
            Defaults to 0, which binds to a random open port of the
            system's choosing.

```
 class Service(service.Service):
  """Object that manages the starting and stopping of the
  GeckoDriver."""

   def __init__(self, executable_path, port=0, service_args=None,
             log_path="geckodriver.log", env=None):
      print(port)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 1000)
```